# Location of android SDK has not been setup in preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt, android-2.2-froyo

I am getting this error:
[image]

I have installed ADT and SDK using install new software in Eclipse. I am using `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 2`.

I used this link https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I do not know where the SDK is getting installed as it being done through Eclipse. Which path should I provide to remove this error. Actually I cannot even set a path as the OK button in preferences window remains disabled.

What can be the issue.

I know this has be address earlier but could not get what I am looking for hence added a new thread.

Comment: You should download Android SDK for setting this up. You can find links [from here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)

Comment: open
Windows->preferences->Android[from leftside]->Browse->take the path were the sdk lies and press apply[download android sdk from developers.android.com]

Comment: I cannot browse the path of SDK as I have not downloaded it. It was being done through Eclipse (Install new software). So no clue where it is being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know where the SDK is getting installed as it being done through Eclipse.

Not if you installed the ADT plugin separately. You need to [download and install the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) (see "SDK Tools Only"), then teach the ADT plugin where you installed it.

Also note that support for the ADT Plugin has been officially discontinued by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Window>preferences>Android

In the SDK location Text Box you need to browse the location of Android SDK, to let eclipse know where the android SDK is, and same for the ADT by chhosing HELP>Install new Software...

Comment: I have not downloaded SDK individually, I had downloaded it using Install new Software window from Eclipse. So I don't really know the location of where it getting downloaded internally.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem and get solution....

In Eclipse go to Help

Install New Software ---> Add

Inside Add Repository write the Name: ADT (or, as you want)

and Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

after loading some time you will get Developer Tools.

check Developer Tool

click Next

Finish

Your problem will solved.

Answer (score -1):

I have deleted folder .android in my user folder (c:/users/xyz/.android) and relaunched Eclipse - dialog box "Android SDK installation" (not exact name) has came up - then install of SDK.